# TexStudio disable file monitoring?

Tags: texstudio

I am using TexStudio on Windows to work with files from a mounted network drive. Sometimes the drive will disappear and have to be remounted.

This is no problem for me, but with a lot of files open TexStudio notices the file is gone and prompts a dialog box for each file asking if i want to reload the file and then if I want to show differences.

This leads to a lot of clicking ignore/cancel.

Is there a way to disable this file monitoring or dialog box?

Comment: `Options` -> `Configure TeXstudio` -> `Adv. Editor` -> Uncheck `Monitor open files for external changes`?

Comment: @Troy Hmm I don't have that option using version 2.11.2

Comment: Is updating TS an option for you? The current version is 2.12.6

Comment: @Troy When was that option introduced?

Comment: 2.12.0 I think.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from version 2.12.0, an option is provided to: (taken from the [changelog](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/CHANGELOG.txt))

> ... deactivate all reactions to external file changes.

This option can be found by following the path below in TeXstudio:

> `Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Adv. Editor -> Monitor open files for external changes`

**Uncheck** the `Monitor open files for external changes` option if you don't want prompts to appear when your open files are subject to external changes.

[image]

(To access the `Adv. Editor` tab, you also need to check the `Show advanced options` option on the bottom left of the `Configure TeXstudio` window.)